# Proving that the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to two bases has a particular form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm doing the conceptual exercises from my linear algebra book, and I ran up to the following exercise:

> Let $\mathbb{V}$ be a vector space with basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ \mathbf{v}_1, \ldots , \mathbf{v}_n \}$, let $\mathbb{W}$ be a vector space with basis $\mathcal{C}$, and let $L : \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{W}$ be a linear mapping. Prove that the matrix ${_{\mathcal{C}}}[L]_{\mathcal{B}}$ defined by $${_\mathcal{C}}[L]_\mathcal{B} = \begin{bmatrix} [L(\mathbf{v}_1)]_\mathcal{C} & \cdots & [L(\mathbf{v}_n)]_\mathcal{C} \end{bmatrix}$$ satisfies $[ L(\mathbf{x}) ]_\mathcal{C} = {_\mathcal{C}}[L]_{\mathcal{B}} [ \mathbf{x} ]_{\mathcal{B}}$ and hence is the **matrix of $L$ with respect to basis $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$**.

I tried to use the following theorem:

> $[L]_{\mathcal{B}} = P^{-1} [L]_{\mathcal{S}}P$.

where  given a vector space $\mathbb{V}$ with basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ \mathbf{v}_1 , \ldots , \mathbf{v}_n \}$, and a linear operator $L : \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$, $$[L]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{bmatrix} [L(\mathbf{v}_1)]_{\mathcal{B}} & \cdots & [L(\mathbf{v}_n)]_{\mathcal{B}} \end{bmatrix}$$ is the *matrix of the linear operator $L$* with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$.

But it got messy as I'm not sure where to apply it, because in the exercise we have to prove the matrix of $L$ with respect of $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$.

Any ideas or solutions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that the matrices (linear maps) are equivalent on the set of basis vectors $v_1,...,v_n$, as both maps are linear. Just try this for an arbitrary vector $v_i \in \mathcal{B}$. It follows by definition.

Answer (score 0):

This exercise is about primary conventions and principles of linear algebra.

When a basis $(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ of the vector space $V$ has been chosen this automatically defines a "coordinate map"
$$V\to{\mathbb R}^n,\qquad x\mapsto (x_1,\ldots x_n)\ ,$$
whereby the resulting $n$-tuple is conventionally written as a column vector
$$\left[\matrix{x_1\cr\vdots\cr x_n\cr}\right]=:[x]\ .$$
This map is linear. Given two such spaces $V$ and $W$ with bases ${\cal V}:=(v_k)_{1\le k\leq n}$ and ${\cal W}:=(w_i)_{1\leq i\leq m}$, and a linear map $L:\>V\to W$ then this setup automatically defines an $(m\times n)$-matrix
$$[L]:=\bigl[l_{ik}\bigr]_{1\leq i\leq m,\ 1\leq k\leq n}$$
according to the following rule: $$l_{ik}:=\bigl(Lv_k\bigr)_i\qquad(1\leq i\leq m,\ 1\leq k\leq n)\ .$$
In words: In the $n$ columns of $L$ we see the ${\cal W}$-coordinates of the vectors $Lv_k$. (This is the matrix denoted by ${}_{\cal W}[L]_{\cal V}$ in your question.)

You are told to prove that under these conventions one automatically has
$$\bigl[ Lx\bigr]=[L][x]\ ,$$
whereby on the right hand side matrix multiplication is understood. The proof is simple: Let $x=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k v_k$. Then $Lx=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\>Lv_k$ and therefore
$$\bigl(Lx\bigr)_i=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\>\bigl(Lv_k\bigr)_i=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\>l_{ik}=\bigl(\bigl[L\bigr][x]\bigr)_i\qquad(1\leq i\leq m)\ .$$